# How to get name of next middleware function in Express.JS

Tags: javascript, express, middleware

I'm trying to get the names of middleware functions in a particular request route.
Let's say I have the following code implemented:

```
const authorizeRoute = (req,res,next) => {
  let nextFunctionName = SomeFunctionToRetrieveTheNameOfTheNextMiddlewareToBeCalled()
  if (isUserAuthorized(req.user.id, nextFunctionName)) next()
}

app.use(authorizeRoute)
app.get("/users", controller.getUsers)
app.get("/users/:id/posts", controller.getUserPosts)
```

I want the `authorizeRoute` middleware to be able to get the name of the middleware function to be called next in the stack.

Like, if there's a `GET` request to `"/users"`, I want the `nextFunctionName` to have the value of `"getUsers"` or "controller.getUsers" or something similar.
Or `GET "/users/:id/posts"` have the same `nextFunctionName` to be `"getUserPosts"` or something.

How will I do this?

I'm still new to Express and Node or even javascript. How would I go about doing this?

I know this is possible somehow because there's already a way to get the function name as a string in javascript.

```
someFunction.name // gives "someFunction" returned as a string
```

So I know it can be done. I just don't know, how.

P.S. I know there are alternate ways of accomplishing the desired effect, but my need for this is not exactly reflected in the above snippet, but I tried my best to have it showcased.

Comment: So, did you try `next.name`? But I don't think `next` is actually the next middleware, but rather a wrapper around it provided by express.

Comment: @Bergi next.name gives "next" as string. besides. next() doesn't directly call the next middleware function. it has other functionalities as well, which I don't know anything about.

Comment: You really shouldn't use function names to select authorisation. Instead, provide it explicitly to the route - this will also scale much better with lots of different routes: `app.get("/users", authorizeRoute("users"), controller.getUsers);
app.get("/users/:id/posts", authorizeRoute("posts"), controller.getUserPosts);`

Comment: I know that's one way to do it. but there's already a database to control access to each route. like I said. the snippet doesn't exactly show why I need it; just what.

Comment: So why do you need it? What you want is probably not possible.

Comment: console.log this and see what you get. ```app._router.stack```. And then try this:  ```app._router.stack[0].handle.name```. Hopefully it puts you on the right track.

Comment: it is possible. i know it is. i know how programs work. if the `next()` can call the next middleware, so can I get the name of the next middleware.
The 'why' is that it's not exactly my design. I'm just trying to make the best of the situation I'm in and learn along the way. i didn't design the database to work like that.

Comment: @Andrew i had tried going that way. but the code was just getting bigger and bigger. with routers and controllers, there's so many layers of middleware to shift through. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong; I'm not even sure.

Comment: @JoseVSebastian "*If the `next()` can call the next middleware, so can I get the name of the `next` middleware.*" - Nope. It's called encapsulation.

Comment: Best you can do is probably inspecting [`req.route`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.route)

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't help. I'm doing it now by giving the authorization middleware the function name as well. I hoped for something better, to have it called dynamically rather than defining it every time. I'm just experimenting...

Comment: @Bergi I'll try inspecting `req.route` more, but I'll probably not change it in the end if it just makes the code messy.

Comment: @Bergi figured it out, thanks.

Comment: @JoseVSebastian Please consider adding [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. I can't put the middleware to get the stack for a route using `app.use` but if the middleware is put among the handlers for the route, it will work.

```
const SomeFunctionToRetrieveTheNameOfTheLastMiddleware(req) => {
  let stack = req.route.stack
  return stack[stack.length-1].name
}

const authorizeRoute = (req,res,next) => {
  let nextFunctionName = SomeFunctionToRetrieveTheNameOfTheLastMiddleware(req)
  if (isUserAuthorized(req.user.id, nextFunctionName)) next()
}

app.get("/users", authorizeRoute, controller.getUsers)
app.get("/users/:id/posts", authorizeRoute, controller.getUserPosts)
```

I had the answer to the question in the question itself

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about route stack in request. And it's not there using direct middleware outside of a particular route. Well done!

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to do something that dynamic, keep it simple. Why not just do this:

```
const nextFunctionName = (user)=>{
    // blah blah blah (something synchronous not asynchronous)
}

const authorizeRoute = (req,res,next) => {

  if (isUserAuthorized(req.user?.id)){
      nextFunctionName(req.user)
    }

   next()
}
```

but it seems like you actually just want to do this:

```
const nextFunctionName = (user, next)=>{
    // blah blah blah
    next();
}

const authorizeRoute = (user, next) => {
  if (isUserAuthorized(user.id)){
      nextFunctionName(user, next); // pass in the next callback
    } else {
      next()
    }
  
}
```

Comment: huh? when did `nextFunctionName` become a function. it's supposed to be a string that's  the name of the next middleware

Comment: yes, EXACTLY :)  think about it

Comment: `isUserAuthorized` function checks the database for the user id and the function the user is trying to access. it's NOT authentication

Comment: your way would definitely work. but I'm not trying to change the functioning of the program, if I were, I wouldn't have to ask this question, there are a lot of resources out there doing it alternatively. What I was looking for, was to fill a gap in my knowledge,  getting names of the middleware functions in a particular route. that was what I lacked. Everything else is secondary.